# Auth0 with linkedin profile returning empty profile

Tags: node.js, auth0

I'm using auth0 nodejs library to try and get a user profile that has login  with linkedin to my application.

So I do the whole oauth dance, do a post to oauth/token with the code received, then first of all I get a response without refresh token, but with access token and other relevant info.

Now with the access token I do a request to /userinfo and it returns empty, however on the auth0 admin page I can see that the user does have a lot of information for his profile.

I'm wondering what I'm missing either in my config or how I instantiate the auth0 client.

Configuration for auth0 is implicit auth,and openid.

Help me debug.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out this depends on the scope sent to the /authorize first call.

If no scope is sent in that scope then you will get an empty profile.

A valid scope in order to get the profile is scope=email,profile,openid